# Successful unzip with wrong password

Tags: python, python-3.x, passwords, zip

My specific question is around what exactly `zipfile.ZipFile(myfile.zip).extractall(thepassword)` actually does.  I'm working through some pentest tutorials and have written the following snippet.

There are two files that the script acts upon.  The first is a zip file that was created using `zip -P very_long_random_string_password -r myfile.zip myfiles.txt`.  This is on Kali Linux from the CLI with Python3 (3.9).  The second file is a list of common passwords from github (`[passlist.txt][1]`).

```
#Python3
from zipfile import ZipFile

with open('passlist.txt', 'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    password = line.strip('\n')
    password = password.encode('utf-8')

    try:
      foundpass = ZipFile('myfile.zip').extractall(pwd=password)
      if foundpass == None:
        print("\nPassword: ", password.decode())
        break
      except RuntimeError:
        pass
```

The expected result would be for the script to try every password in the `passlist.txt` and if the `extractall` method didn't throw a `RuntimeError` to print out the successful password.  If the password is wrong, the program continues.

This in fact does work and I've tried multiple passwords that are caught as expected based on passwords in the `passlist.txt`.  **BUT...**  I wanted to have the script run unsuccessfully and got an unexpected result.

Using a `-P pashdshGivgisudhfagn9879te6rtq6rr` in the zip process, which doesn't exist in the `passlist.txt` resulted in successfully unlocking the zip file using the password `rabbit11`. As it turns out I can unzip the file with `rabbit11` or `pashdshGivgisudhfagn9879te6rtq6rr`.

I've run this several times now with different `very_long_random_string_passwords` and been able to find corresponding `simple_passwords` that will unlock the zip file.

Why?  I don't see any pattern to encoded text and this seems to be odd behavior.

Other examples (I actually haven't found one that doesn't work):

Complex:  `444hdshGivgisudhfagn9879te6rtq6rr`
Simple:   `rugby12`

Complex:  `rszv8FoGGM6JRWGX`
Simple:   `lickme`

Comment: Does [this Stack Exchange post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33081/zip-file-with-two-password) answer the question?

Comment: maybe...  My original test cases were empty files in a directory.  The use of the `simple` password successfully completed the unzip process.  But I tested with files that contain text information inside the file and they do not completed the unzip process.  Still looking - but I guess if the file is blank then it 'successfully' applies with the key but gets the right result (and a successful unzip)?

Comment: One thing I've read is that you can use the same "complex" password on different zipfiles with different contents, but it will be different "simple" passwords which (apparently) succeed in unzipping the different files. It's something to do with the connection between zip encryption and the CRC sum of the contents. If you are able to find new password collisions on your nonempty zip files, I'll be curious to know if you really get the original contents back, or if you get garbage back, like answer to the linked post says you wlil.

Comment: @Noah - In looking closer, is the fact that the wrong password both successfully returns the correct checksum on the last byte and successfully returns the correct checksum on an empty file (decrypts an empty file) what allows it to succeed?  Whereas, a file that has something in it may successfully return the checksum on the last byte, but ultimately cannot successfully return the checksum on the entire file and therefore doesn't decrypt?  If that makes sense, then yes.

Comment: I think that is what the top answer to that linked post is saying, yes.